# this Operation is not supported in WCF Test Client Error

Tags: wcf, servicecontract, wcftestclient

Actually i implemented WCF service in IIS Host

Using WCF Test Client tool I get this error: "this Operation is not supported in WCF Test Client".

http://desbiz:49615/GestionProvision.svc

Using wsdl in IExplorer all is ok.

http://desbiz:49615/GestionProvision.svc?wsdl

The contract is:

```
namespace Security.Provision.ServiceContracts.Interfaces

{

[ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://Security.Provision")]

public interface IProvision

{

[OperationContract]

RespuestaProvision CrearUsuario(PeticionUsuarioProvision peticion);

[OperationContract]

RespuestaProvision ModificarUsuario(PeticionUsuarioProvision peticion);

[OperationContract]

RespuestaProvision BajaUsuario(PeticionUsuarioProvision peticion);

[OperationContract]

RespuestaProvision HabilitarDeshabilitarUsuario(PeticionUsuarioProvision peticion);

[OperationContract]

RespuestaProvision SavePuestoTipo(PeticionPuestoTipoProvision peticion);

[OperationContract]

RespuestaObtenerEmpleado GetEmpleado(PeticionUsuarioProvision peticion);

}

}
```

May i know the reason.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,

Comment: Are your input and output parameters defined as [DataContract] ?

Answer (score 2):

You must be using some DataSet or DataTable witn [DataMember] attribute in some custom type, is ok for WCF but the test application cant handle it.

Answer (score 1):

You should also check the you are not using any 'Tuple' as this was not working for me.

```
[DataMember(Name = "IPAddresses")]
public List<Tuple<IPAddress, IPAddress>> IPAddresses { get; set; }
```